# How to write an anonymous JavaScript function in a UML class diagram

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, uml, class-diagram

I want to write a class diagram for a single class(as an example). It has an anonymous callback function. How do I show that function in the class-diagram.

Is writing the function as:
`+function(req, res, next):void` ok?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
});
```

Comment: You should explain the purpose of your class diagram. Is it for documenting library classes such as the Epress library's `Router` class?

Comment: @GerdWagner The purpose of the class diagram is to document an App developed using Express and NodeJs.

Answer (score -1):

OK I got the solution. This is how we are supposed to write a callback function in a UML class-diagram:

```
+get(rule:String,callback:HandlerCallback)
```

Comment: What you need is the Delegate design pattern. The delegation is abstracted to an interface.

Comment: Ammar, your answer shows how to notate the function parameter. It is of type HandlerCallback. Does this mean that there is class called HandlerCallback? How would this class look like in a class diagram?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl There is probably a builtin HandlerCallback class and you will need to ask that as a Question on StackOverflow as how will it look in a class diagram since I am not very expert with it.

Comment: Actually, I'm an expert. There is no official standard UML notation for anonymous callback functions. I think the solution you described is okay, but you should document somewhere (in plain text) that HandlerCallback is supposed to represent an anonymous callback function.